# How do I add multiple sort column in ROW_NUMBER() OVER with case clause in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I add multiple order by row_number over (order by)

I have this code and it doesn't seem to work

```
;WITH CTE_Results AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @lSortCol = @firstNameLit AND @sortDirection=@ascLit THEN [FirstName] END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @lSortCol = @firstNameLit AND @sortDirection=@descLit THEN [FirstName] END DESC,

    CASE WHEN @lSortCol = @lastNameLit AND @sortDirection=@ascLit THEN [LastName] END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @lSortCol = @lastNameLit AND @sortDirection=@descLit THEN [LastName] END DESC,
    --Sort Column no match
    CASE WHEN @sortDirection=@ascLit THEN [LastName] END ASC, [FirstName] ASC,  --This doesn't work
    CASE WHEN @sortDirection=@descLit THEN [LastName] END DESC, [FirstName] ASC  --This doesn't work
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Is it simply because it's missing a closing parenthesis?

Comment: You should use dynamic SQL or separate queries for the different cases.

Comment: Could you provide and example?